# ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessor_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' when using Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

There are several questions with the exact same error, such as:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991972/importerror-cannot-import-name-preprocessor-pb2) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50991972/importerror-cannot-import-name-preprocessor-pb2) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66341528/cannot-run-object-detector-issues-on-windows-importerror-cannot-import-name-s)

But none of them were able to solve my problem. I tried the main solutions which I will describe later.

I have also tried contacting the author of the tutorial on the related Github repository, but they don't seem to be very responsive about it.

I am trying to replicate a workflow for object detecting on satellite images as detailed [here](https://github.com/GIScience/ohsome2label/tree/master/walkthrough)

This walkthough is however intended for working directly on a machine and not on a Jupyter Notebook/Google Colab I think, because the steps are listed in such a way that you are installing everything from scratch.

I want to replicate this workflow on Google Colab so that I can use the free GPU.

I can get everything working up to the actual training, simply by trial and error and adjusting as I go. But I cannot get it to train properly.

I just always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'preprocessor_pb2' from 'object_detection.protos' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/protos/__init__.py)
```

I have created a simplified Colab notebook [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PKi4FIyPOKjFmX-a2Nwj-1gKIQMuZ25D#scrollTo=kwo1-bDSyBV_) with links to the training data hosted on my Google Drive so that anyone can run it.

As you can see in the Colab, I install the package like this:

```
%cd /content/models/research
!python setup.py build
!pip install .
```

...

```
%cd /content/models/research
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

%cd /content/models/research/object_detection

%env PYTHONPATH="/content/models/research:/content/models/research/slim"
!echo "PYTHONPATH is:"
!echo $PYTHONPATH

!python train.py --logtostderr \
  --train_dir training/ \
  --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_inception_v2_coco.config
```

which implements the main solution in the other stackoverflow question threads at the beginning of this question. But it still complains about missing modules, and I don't know what else I can do to make it work.

Any ideas?

Comment: This [notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tf2_colab.ipynb) works for me.

Comment: Try the suggested workaround mentioned in this thread https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2833#issuecomment-346325244